# Newbie in c++ is stuck

Tags: c++, string, function, while-loop, ofstream

i started learning c++ last week and ive finally learned enough to try and stand on my own feets. well guess what i have a problem. the program im trying to make will ask for a file already existing or creates a new one if the name isnt found, and places information in the file lines. when you type -1 you close the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string x;
 string Input;
 int line=0;

 cout << "Please enter the name of the file with the file type" << endl;
 cin >> x;

 ofstream SelectedFile;
 SelectedFile.open(x);

 while(Input != "-1"){
  cout << "Enter the content of the " << line <<" line, or type -1 to quit." << endl;
  cin >> Input;
  line++;
 }
 SelectedFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an error? Does it not do what you expect?

Comment: Try indenting the code? BTW - You have one set of feet

Comment: Looks like the problem is forgetting to write to the file.

Comment: When posting a question to Stackoverflow, please remember to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're having a compile error because `std::ofstream::open` does not take an `std::string` as an argument in C++98 standard. Try this one:

```
SelectedFile.open(x.c_str());
```

Or compile with C++11 support.

**Update**: Where you write things into file? I think you forgot to write that part

```
SelectedFile << line << std::endl ;
```

Comment: To expand on sorush's explanation, C++ has 2 main kinds of strings for historical reasons: The std::string which has built-in features like searching, tracks its own size, etc. and the old C-style string (`c_str`) which is a simple array of type `char`. Many C++ methods take only one or the other, but as Sorush showed, it is easy to convert between them (just not always obvious when you are just starting).

Comment: i know im not supposed to say thank you but ill do it either way. BTW your suggestion on doing (SelectedFile << line << std::endl;) would be correct if you replaced the variable line with Input. also the program works like a charm except that it includes "-1" in the last line. minor problem but ill figure it out